# Cannot get value from nested json

Tags: c#, json, restsharp

I'm deserializing a JSON object into a class that I created using json2csharp. Once deserialized, I cannot access the nested values of this object. The error I get is this:

System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

This is the class I created;

```
public class Ticker
{
    public List<object> error { get; set; }
    public Result result { get; set; }

    public class Result
    {
        public XXBTZCAD XBTCAD { get; set; }


        public class XXBTZCAD
        {
            public List<string> a { get; set; }
            public List<string> b { get; set; }
            public List<string> c { get; set; }
            public List<string> v { get; set; }
            public List<string> p { get; set; }
            public List<int> t { get; set; }
            public List<string> l { get; set; }
            public List<string> h { get; set; }
            public string o { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the JSON string, at the time of this writing:

```
{
  "error": [

  ],
  "result": {
 "XXBTZCAD": {
  "a": [
    "4776.10000",
    "8",
    "8.000"
  ],
  "b": [
    "4773.90000",
    "1",
    "1.000"
  ],
  "c": [
    "4776.20000",
    "0.02510294"
  ],
  "v": [
    "4.85183508",
    "61.15237421"
  ],
  "p": [
    "4775.02293",
    "4767.92898"
  ],
  "t": [
    126,
    608
  ],
  "l": [
    "4756.70000",
    "4720.60000"
  ],
  "h": [
    "4780.00000",
    "4783.30000"
  ],
  "o": "4776.40000"
 }
 }
}
```

This is the code that deserializes and attempts to display the first value of List a

```
    private async void GetKraken(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var client = new RestClient();
        IRestResponse response;
        Ticker BTCCADTicker = new Ticker();
        client.BaseUrl = new Uri("https://api.kraken.com/0/public/Ticker?pair=XBTCAD");
        var request = new RestRequest();
        response = await client.ExecuteTaskAsync(request);
        BTCCADTicker = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Ticker>(response.Content);
        MessageBox.Show(BTCCADTicker.result.XBTCAD.a[0]);
    }
```

I would expect to see a value around 4700 to be returned, but I'm getting the error above instead. What gives? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You haven't shown any JSON?

Comment: The JSON is here: https://api.kraken.com/0/public/Ticker?pair=XBTCAD 

Also updated post with the JSON data.

Comment: You should always include it in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't defined `XXBTZCAD` in your model. You've called it `XBTCAD` by mistake. Fixed it looks like this:

```
public class Ticker
{
    public List<object> error { get; set; }
    public Result result { get; set; }

    public class Result
    {
        public XXBTZCAD XXBTZCAD { get; set; }


        public class XXBTZCAD
        {
            public List<string> a { get; set; }
            public List<string> b { get; set; }
            public List<string> c { get; set; }
            public List<string> v { get; set; }
            public List<string> p { get; set; }
            public List<int> t { get; set; }
            public List<string> l { get; set; }
            public List<string> h { get; set; }
            public string o { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

I see now that this is the same name as the nested class. I'd recommend the simple solution of not nesting your classes:

```
public class Ticker
{
    public List<object> error { get; set; }
    public Result result { get; set; }
}

public class Result
{
    public XXBTZCAD XXBTZCAD { get; set; }
}



public class XXBTZCAD
{
    public List<string> a { get; set; }
    public List<string> b { get; set; }
    public List<string> c { get; set; }
    public List<string> v { get; set; }
    public List<string> p { get; set; }
    public List<int> t { get; set; }
    public List<string> l { get; set; }
    public List<string> h { get; set; }
    public string o { get; set; }
}
```

If you really want to nest them, simply rename `class XXBTZCAD` to something else. It's the property name that's important for deserialization, not the type name.

Comment: Tried that originally, but I get this error 

"The type 'Ticker.Result' already contains a definition for 'XXBTZCAD'"

Comment: @Sterlingz Updated

Comment: There is no problem with nested classes in this case if you append Data to the class names. ResultData and XXBTZCADData ;o)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest copy your JSON and in Visual Studio :

> Edit > Paste Special > Parse JSON As Classes

```
public class Ticker
{
    public object[] error { get; set; }
    public Result result { get; set; }
}

public class Result
{
    public XXBTZCAD XXBTZCAD { get; set; }
}

public class XXBTZCAD
{
    public string[] a { get; set; }
    public string[] b { get; set; }
    public string[] c { get; set; }
    public string[] v { get; set; }
    public string[] p { get; set; }
    public int[] t { get; set; }
    public string[] l { get; set; }
    public string[] h { get; set; }
    public string o { get; set; }
}
```

and you can use this method to get the result :

```
public static async Task<string> GetKraken()
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("https://api.kraken.com/0/public/Ticker?pair=XBTCAD");
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    return responseBody;
}
```

and then use the method and convert it to get actual object:

```
var ticker = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Ticker>(GetKraken().Result);
```